# Xamarin.ios: Search bar displays in every tab bar view

Tags: xamarin.ios, tabs, mvvmcross, searchbar, tabview

I'm building an iOS app with Xamarin.ios MvvmCross. In this app I use a tabbed view. on one tab view I wan't to display a search bar, but this search bar displays in every tab view. Anyone know how to resolve this so that I can hide the search bar in the other tab views?

Search bar Tab view:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(Boolean animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        var searchController = new UISearchController(searchResultsController: null);

        searchController.SearchBar.SizeToFit();
        searchController.SearchBar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent;

        TabBarController.NavigationItem.HidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false;
        TabBarController.NavigationItem.SearchController = searchController;

        NavigationController.NavigationBar.PrefersLargeTitles = true;
        this.Title = "Search";

        _searchBar = searchController.SearchBar;
        _searchBar.SearchButtonClicked += SearchBar_SearchButtonClicked;
        _searchBar.TextChanged += SearchBarOnTextChanged;
        _searchBar.CancelButtonClicked += SearchBarOnCancelButtonClicked;

        TabBarController.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = null;
    }
```

Picture of tab view with search bar:
[Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft37C.png)

Other tab views where I want to hide the search bar but can't get it done:

```
    public override void ViewWillAppear(Boolean animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        //var searchController = new UISearchController(searchResultsController: null);
        //searchController.SearchBar.Hidden = true;

        var search = new UISearchController(searchResultsController: null);
        TabBarController.NavigationItem.HidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true;
        search.SearchBar.Hidden = true;

        NavigationController.NavigationBar.PrefersLargeTitles = true;
        TabBarController.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = null;
    }
```

Picture of tab view where I don't want to show the search bar:
[Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2SGf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs because you just use one Navigation Controller wrapping your TabbarController. When user enter the second tabbar item(Search), you initialize a `UISearchController` and set it to the `NavigationItem`'s `SearchController`. So this search bar appears as you want.

But when you return to the `Home` controller, this `UISearchController` will be still there since you just use one `UINavigationController`. Add the code below in your `Home` Controller's `ViewWillAppear()` event will fix your issue:

```
TabBarController.NavigationItem.SearchController = null;
```

I really recommend you to separate your one `UINavigationController` to four in your situation. Then each tabbar item controller has its own `NavigationItem` and will not affect each other. `UITabbarController` should be your app's root ViewController. Your app's hierarchy can be like this:
[image]
I use storyboard to draw two tabbar items helping you understand what I mean.

In this way in the Home controller, there's no need to add any code. You can just add the search bar in your Search controller with the code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    var searchController = new UISearchController(searchResultsController: null);

    searchController.SearchBar.SizeToFit();
    searchController.SearchBar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent;

    this.NavigationItem.HidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false;
    this.NavigationItem.SearchController = searchController;

    NavigationController.NavigationBar.PrefersLargeTitles = true;
    this.Title = "Search";

    _searchBar = searchController.SearchBar;
    _searchBar.SearchButtonClicked += _searchBar_SearchButtonClicked; ;
    _searchBar.TextChanged += _searchBar_TextChanged; ;
    _searchBar.CancelButtonClicked += _searchBar_CancelButtonClicked; ;

    this.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = null;
}
```

I move your code to `ViewDidLoad()` event and modify `TabBarController.NavigationItem` to `this.NavigationItem`.